# Unable to remove my action bar shadow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My style.xml file

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">

        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <!-- <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->


</resources>
```

My Manifest

```
  <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

I am using action bar v7 compact support library. I was unable to remove my action bar shadow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void forceTabs() {
            try {
                Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
                setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
                setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
            }
            catch(final Exception e) {
                // Handle issues as needed: log, warn user, fallback etc
                // This error is safe to ignore, standard tabs will appear.
            }
      }
```

Call this method in your oncreate method.